# Propulsion power necessary to overcome drag

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, drag

Say I'm riding a bicycle with a tailwind / headwind.
To calculate the drag force, I'd use the relative speed of the bicycle with respect to the air.
But then to calculate my power output, would it be:
Power = drag force * speed with respect to the ground
or
Power = drag force * speed with respect to the air?

I think it would be the latter, but I'm not sure. Here is my reasoning: I do work when I exert a force against the drag, even when I'm standing still with respect to the ground. Therefore it necessary has to be the latter. But is the reasoning correct?

Comment: If there's no displacement, there's no work done. Assuming an immobile object in the frame of reference of the ground and getting a null work as a result is not a contradiction. It's not because there's a force that there's work (no work is done if you push a wall that remains perfectly still)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the speed with respect to the ground, because the formula for power is obtained from the formula for work, which is: force*displacement, and you measure displacement with respect to the ground. Then dividing work by time you will obtain: displacement / time = velocity w.r.t. ground

Comment: my comment to @silverrahul answer: the velocity of air is already taken into account in the force (F=k*v or even k*v^2), so the bigger speed of the wind the bigger the value of force, hence the bigger the value of power needed. But the formula for power is still Power = drag force * speed with respect to the ground

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you are talking only about the component of power required to overcome aerodynamic drag.
The total power required will also have to account for friction  .

As far as the power required just for aerodynamic drag is concerned, it will be equal to

Power = drag force * speed with respect to the air

Think about a small example .
You might want to go at , say 10 kmph with respect to the ground, but you will need more power if wind is blowing at 300 kmph , rather than 5 kmph.
So, your speed with respect to the ground, stays the same, but power required changes based on your speed with respect to the air.

Comment: I agree with the comment of Ramil in saying that your example does not prove your point. If you just take your formula as is, you would predict that some wind exerts work on an immobile object. I discuss that in my answer

Comment: Some wind DOES exert work on an immobile object , in the relevant reference frame. The work exerted will be different in different reference frames.

Comment: Yes, that is the content of my answer. But your answer did not reflect that, and does not reflect the fact that the total work exerted on the system has to be zero in this case (even when taking an exotic reference frame), making it potentially confusing. Your answer can easily be read as saying that your formula is *the* correct definition of power, and that you can not take the speed with respect to the ground, which is not true

Comment: My answer was assuming one particular reference frame. That is what i assumed the OP meant. Unless he meant different

Comment: Well, the question looks to me like it's precisely about a confusion between two potential RF to consider

Comment: @BarbaudJulien Okay , i guess it is upto the OP what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

Which speed you use just depends what reference frame (RF) you want to compute your work in. Work done by a force depends on the choice of RF.

We can define the infinitesimal amount of work done by a force $\textbf{F}$ during a time $dt$ by:
$$\delta W= \textbf{F}.\textbf{v}dt$$

As $\textbf{v}$ depends on your choice of RF, so does the work done by that force (which is just an integration over time of the above quantity). This does not mean that the *total* work will change. I will explain it by adressing the example in the OP, of an immobile object wrt the earth, with air flowing on it:

**In the RF of the earth:**

No displacement. No work. One way to think about it is that you could just glue the object to the ground to compensate the wind. No energy input needed. No work.

**In the RF of the flowing air**:

We assume a constant speed of wind $v$, parallel to the ground.
In that RF, the object moves with a constant speed, and the drag exerts work against it. This is no contradiction with the example above. If we imagine an object glued to the ground, then this very ground, which has a speed v, is exerting work on the object (it is the ground that “pushes” the object through the air in this RF, just like it was the ground that was holding it in place in the previous example). As the object is moving at constant speed in this RF, we know that total force must be zero on it. So both opposite works done by the air and the ground compensate, and in the end no total work is done on the object.

The take away is that energies are defined up to a constant and are not frame-invariant (think about the kinetic energy). So the work done by the wind is not the same in different RF. But in your example of an immobile object, we can see that the total work done on it is always zero (which makes physical sense with the idea that it can maintain this state without requiring any energy input)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my poor english. My native language is french.

The power associated with a forces on a solid in translation is indeed $\vec{F}\vec{v}$ with the velocity $\vec{v}$ in the chosen reference frame.
As indicated in the other posts, this power depends on the RF chosen. For your bicycle, the power associated with the air in the bicycle reference frame is zero.

Does that mean that you don't tire yourself out to pedal in the bicycle reference frame ? obviously no !

The kinetic energy theorem in differential form is : $\frac{dE_c}{dt}=P_{ext}+P_{int}$

with $P_{ext}$ the power of exterior forces and $P_{int}$ the power of interior forces. (action of a part of the system on another part of it)

- In the reference frame linked to the ground : the power of the interior forces is that which the cyclist provides. The power of external forces is that related to the air. The power of the forces of the ground on the bicycle is zero because there is rolling without slipping and the speed of the wheel in contact with the ground is zero. In total, $P_ {int} = - P_ {air}> 0$
- In the reference frame linked to the bicycle, the power of the interior forces is not changed : still that which the cyclist provides. But the power of external forces of to the air on the bicycle is zero.
  But here, the power of the forces of the ground on the bicycle is not zero because in this reference frame, the speed of the wheel in contact with the ground is not zero. This power is positive because the ground pushes the bicycle forward : $P_ {int} = - P_ {ground}> 0$

We get tired in the same way regardless of the chosen frame of reference !